# Django 1.6 ORM count subset of related items

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have these models

```
class BlogEntry(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToMany(Tag, ...)
    ...

class Tag(models.Model):
    ...
```

and a subset of tags:

```
tag_list = list(*some tag objects*)   # can refactor to queryset
```

I need to get the number of tags for each BlogEntry that is in my tags list, so something like this:

```
# Non-working code ahead
BlogEntry.objects.annotate(match=Count(tags__in=tag_list))
```

I've got this code to run just fine

```
# working code ahead
for entry in BlogEntry.objects.all():
        match = len(set(entry.tags.all()).intersection(tag_list))
```

But I feel like doing the counting and intersecting in python rather than in the database could pose a performance issue down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation on the [order of annotate() and filter() clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses).

As that section says, if you filter before you annotate, then the annotation will only include elements matched by the filter. So:

```
BlogEntry.objects.filter(tags__in=tag_list).annotate(match=Count(tags))
```

Comment: I'd never thought this would work in ManyToManyFields as well, thanks a lot!